# Windows 8 Disk Check on startup

Tags: windows-8, chkdsk

So I have a windows 8 box that may or may not actually have something wrong with it. But right now the most important thing to me is to get it to skip the disk check so I can actually see what is happening. How can I do this? Is there any button I can pretty that tells it "yes I know you want to check the disk but I don't care".

This is the third time it has been through this in the past day, each time takes many hours. But I'm not going to sit at work all day on a Saturday waiting for a damn check disk to run for the fourth time. Especially because I want to boot up the machine so a remote job can tell it to reimage itself.

Comment: On Windows 8, i was given an option to skip Disk check by hitting a key before it starts. Are you sure you don't see the prompt?

Answer (score 2):

- open regedit.exe and browse to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`
- Edit the value for *BootExecute* from `autocheck autochk *`  to `autocheck autochk /k:c *`

Comment: Hello bhanu, can you please explain what the new parameter /k:c does?

Comment: @nixda - Enabled a disk check before windows starts on drive `c` look up the reverse question 'how to disable it" and you will understand the command itself.